# Image Upload with flutter http MultipartFile

Tags: flutter, http, dart

Now I am creating a function for uploading image with Flutter by using **http** package

This is the code for uploading image to server

```
Future<String> uploadNewImage(String imagePath) async {
  var postUri = Uri.parse("https://test.vahupu.com/g2.php?mode=fileupload");
  var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", postUri);
  request.files.add(
    await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      "file",
      imagePath,
      filename: imagePath.split("/").last,
    ),
  );
  var response = await request.send();
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var responseString = await response.stream.bytesToString();
    var responseJson = json.decode(responseString);
    if (responseJson.isEmpty) {
      showErrorDialog("Server Error");
      return "";
    } else {
      showErrorDialog("Image Uploaded Succesfully");
      return responseJson["filepath"];
    }
  } else {
    showErrorDialog("Something Went Wrong");
  }
  return "";
}
```

The imagePath is comes from the image_picker package

```
Future _getImgFromGallery() async {
  XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery,
    imageQuality: 50,
  );
  if (image != null) {
    String imageName = await uploadNewImage(
      image.path,
    );
    if (imageName != "") {
      widget.addOrRemoveImage(imageNameList, image.path);
    }
  }
}
```

This api endpoint works fine with my Thunderclient(altnertative for POSTMAN).
[image: Screenshot for image uploading with Thunderclient]

But the code does not works with the flutter app, and the API returns an empty response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I Got the solution...

In server side api validate the document by using `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` operation in php

but the http.MultipartFile function sends the data with `application/octet-stream`

so the if condition not executed in the server side. so the api returns an empty repsonse.

`content-type: MediaType.parse("image/png")` I added this lines to the http.MultipartFile function. so i resolved this issue